# Linguagem para desenvolver um sistema de live

Tags: php, javascript, html, node.js, angular

Estou interessado nos sistemas de live ex, facebook;youtube entre outros oferece esses serviços, em qual linguagem isso é feito, por onde eu começo a estudar?

Basicamente quero acessar a camera de um celular especifico e transmitir para quem estiver online no site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso você precisará de uma comunicação entre os dois você pode teria que criar um servidor que comunica isso ou usar um pronto com API. Como por exemplo o Nexmo que fornece um canal de voz e vídeo. Isso se chama WebRTC.

Quanto a utilização da câmera precisa saber o que seu projeto precisa, existem aplicações para celulares nativas e híbridas. Eu hoje uso híbrida com um projeto que se chama cordova, mas também estou iniciando um projeto em kotlin.

Sabendo disso para conectar os dois pontos você precisará de um WebRTC se usar a nexmo eles tem SDK para conexão com qualquer linguagem como : PHP, JavaScript entre outras.

Estou sendo bem raso no assunto porque são tópicos completamente diferentes que exigem um estudo em profundidade mas vou colocar algumas tecnologias para você dar uma olhada e ir mais  fundo.

- WebRTC;
- Websocket;
- Ionic;
- Cordova;
- React Native;
- Kotlin;
- OpenTok;

Vai fundo tenho certeza que vendo todas essas coisas vai começar a conectar os pontos para chegar onde precisa.